# Creating Life game in java

Tags: java

I am making a life game.

The following code is meant to check how many neighbours that a point has.

```
public int neighbours(int x, int y){
    int result = 0;
if(x!=0 && y!=0 && y!=getHeight() && x!= getLength()){
    if (life[x - 1][y + 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x][y + 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x + 1][y + 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x + 1][y] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x + 1][y - 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x][y - 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x - 1][y - 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x - 1][y] == 1)
        result++;
} else if(x==0 && y==0){
    if (life[x][y + 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x + 1][y + 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x + 1][y] == 1)
        result++;
}
else if(x==0 && y==getHeight()){
    if (life[x + 1][y] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x + 1][y - 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x][y - 1] == 1)
        result++;
}
else if(y==getHeight() && x==getLength()){
    if (life[x][y - 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x - 1][y - 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x - 1][y] == 1)
        result++;
}
else if(y==0 && x==getLength()){
    if (life[x - 1][y + 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x][y + 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x - 1][y] == 1)
        result++;
}
else if (x==0){
    if (life[x][y + 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x + 1][y + 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x + 1][y] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x + 1][y - 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x][y - 1] == 1)
        result++;
}
else if(y==getHeight()){
    if (life[x + 1][y] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x + 1][y - 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x][y - 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x - 1][y - 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x - 1][y] == 1)
        result++;
}
else if(x==getLength()){
    if (life[x - 1][y + 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x][y + 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x][y - 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x - 1][y - 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x - 1][y] == 1)
        result++;
}
else if(y==0 && x!=getLength() && x!=0){
    if (life[x - 1][y + 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x][y + 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x + 1][y + 1] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x + 1][y] == 1)
        result++;
    else if (life[x - 1][y] == 1)
        result++;
}
    return result;
}
```

As you can see, I have tried to address all exceptions but the program keeps giving me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 30
at LifeGrid.neighbours(LifeGrid.java:165)
at LifeGrid.run(LifeGrid.java:179)
at TestLife.main(TestLife.java:15)
```

Do you guys have any idea why the out of bounds exception still happens when I treated all possible exceptions.

Comment: Oh my god. My eyes. There must be a better way.

Comment: What do getHeight() and getLength() do/return?

Comment: Can you please indicate which line is line 165 of LifeGrid.java, so we know where the error happens?

Comment: Your current algorithm, if it worked, will only return 0 or 1. Perhaps you want to replace all `else if` with just `if`?

Comment: A lot of those `else if` statements need to be `if`, because in most circumstances, you'll want several of them to run, not just the first one that's encountered.

Comment: This code is hard to read and understand.  It looks like too much code to me.  There's a better, cleaner, more concise, more elegant way to do it.  Not very object-oriented, either.

Comment: else if (life[x + 1][y + 1] == 1)
this is the 165th line code

Comment: lol Cruncher I know :) I do hope to find a better way

Comment: It's OK.  Get it working first, then think about refactoring it.  It's OK to have code like this while it's work in progress.  Just so long as it's a whole lot cleaner when it goes into production.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check < getHeight/Width(), not ==.  If it's == getHeight or getWidth it will be out of bounds.

Comment: And also just make it `x >= 0 && y >= 0` just to be sure. It's common practice.

Comment: Almost but not quite correct.  He/she is doing those checks to see if the cell is ON the edge of the board, not within the board.

Answer (score 0):

Your checks for `y == getHeight()` need to be `y == getHeight() - 1`, because that's the value you'll have when you're on the bottom edge of the board.  Also, your checks for `x == getLength()` need to be `x == getLength() - 1`, because that's the value you'll have when you're on the right hand edge of the board.